# jQuery animate box

Tags: javascript, jquery, position, jquery-animate

I have a box i want to animate when clicked on a link. The link is inside the box - therefore i can not hide the box and the use a simple slideToggle function.
I want the box to slide to position bottom: 0px;, and when clicked again it should slide to bottom: -71px;

This is my box' HTML:

```
    <!-- LOGIN -->
<div id="userlogin">
    <div class="topbutton"><a href="#"><span>Log ind</span></a></div>
    <form action="" method="POST" enctype="" onsubmit="document.getElementById('_form__submit').disabled = true;" target="" id="_form__form">
        <input type="hidden" name="module" value="Brugere" id="_form__module">
        <input type="hidden" name="page" value="login" id="_form__page">
        <input type="hidden" name="do" value="" id="_form__do">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="0" id="_form__id">
        <input type="hidden" name="lang_id" value="da" id="_form__lang_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="_form_" id="_form_" value="submit">
        <input type="hidden" name="when_done" value="" id="when_done">

        <div class="left">
            <p><span>Brugernavn</span><input type="text" name="username" value="" id="username" class="loginfield" /></p>
            <p><span>Adgangskode</span><input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password" class="loginfield" /></p>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <input type="submit" id="_form__submit" class="loginbutton" value="Log ind" /><br />
            <a href="/site/da/Brugere/forgot_password"><b>»</b> Glemt adgangskode?</a>
            <iframe width="0" height="0" src="" name="_form__iframe_save" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </form>
</div>
<!-- LOGIN -->
```

And this is the jQuery so far

```
    $("#userlogin .topbutton a").click(function () {
    $("#userlogin").stop(true).animate({bottom: '0'}, {speed: 500});
}, function () {
    $("#userlogin").stop(true).animate({bottom: '-71px'}, {speed: 500});
});
```

But this doesn't work, so can someone please help me? :)

Comment: Please explain _exectly_ what doesn't work?

Comment: The [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method does not accept two handlers. You want to toggle between the two?

Comment: OT: you should bring a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`toggle-event`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) method.

```
$("#userlogin .topbutton a").toggle(
function() {
    $("#userlogin").stop(true).animate({
        bottom: '0'
    }, 500);
}, function() {
    $("#userlogin").stop(true).animate({
        bottom: '-71px'
    }, 500);
});
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/5ChVX/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    $("#userlogin .topbutton a").click(function () {
    $("#userlogin").stop(true).animate({bottom: '0'}, 500);
}, function () {
    $("#userlogin").stop(true).animate({bottom: '-71px'}, 500);
});
```

Comment: Just curious, but why do you have to call STOP first?  What exactly are you stopping?

Comment: @Prisoner, the animation from the previous click (*if it has not ended yet*)

Comment: Ah! Gotcha....thank you very much!  One more thing, does calling STOP return the object to it's original (default) state (or position)?  Or does it merely stop the previous animation (wherever it happens to be at the moment)?

Comment: @PrisonerZERO: cleaning queue, it means that it stop, as Gaby said,previous animation